# Statistics on Cauchy Distributed Data

Tags: resonance, statistics, data-analysis

So the Cauchy/Lorentz distribution is often used to describe distributions in physics (e.g. resonance). But theoretically, the Cauchy/Lorentz Distribution does not have a defined mean and variance, and the central limit theorem is not applicable.

What consequences does this have on the statistics that can be performed in these kinds of situations? I would assume that this is severely limiting?